# java.lang.NullPointerException: 'void org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, nullpointerexception, nullable

I making an app to detect potholes this the main function camera fragment where I have to use opencv to get the desired result
while using opencv in android java I am facing this issue please help me :
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(int)' on a null object reference

package com.example.dpgra.defectdetect;

```
/*import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;*/
//import model.CameraBridgeViewBase;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import model.Darknet;
import model.Pothole;
import model.PotholeList;

public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2, View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private View rootView;
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    private Darknet net;
    private static CameraFragment cameraFragment;
    private PotholeList potholeList;
    private Integer OrientationIsValid;
    private double confidenceThresh;
    BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback ;
    Mat imageMat;
   // JavaCameraView javaCamera2View;



    private static String TAG ="CameraFragment";
    static
    {

        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV Installed Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV Failed");
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    private CameraFragment() {
        super();
        potholeList = PotholeList.getInstance();
        OrientationIsValid = 0;
        confidenceThresh = .6;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the one instance of the camera fragment.
     *
     * @return the camera fragment
     */
    public static CameraFragment getInstance() {
        if (cameraFragment == null) {
            cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();
        }
        return cameraFragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);
        this.rootView = rootView;
//        javaCamera2View= (JavaCameraView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
        //Check if the device is not an emulator
        String myDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;

        if (!myDeviceModel.toLowerCase().contains("sdk")) {
            //Rotate the camera view 90 degrees clockwise
            mOpenCvCameraView.setAngle(90);
//            javaCamera2View.setAngle(90);
        }
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton2).setOnClickListener(this);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
//        javaCamera2View.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        SeekBar seekBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);



        /**
         * Makes sure opencv can load successfully.
         */

        BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this.getActivity()) {
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {

                switch (status) {
                    case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS: {
                        //Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                        mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
//                       javaCamera2View.enableView();
                        imageMat = new Mat();
                        break;

                    }
                    default: {
                        super.onManagerConnected(status);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };


        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked when camera preview has started. After this method is invoked
     * the frames will start to be delivered to client via the onCameraFrame() callback.
     *
     * @param width  -  the width of the frames that will be delivered
     * @param height - the height of the frames that will be delivered
     */
    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

        /*
        if(OrientationIsValid == 2) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext())
                    .setTitle("Alert")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to keep this orientation?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    OrientationIsValid = 0;
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    OrientationIsValid = 1;
                }
            }).show();
        }
        */
        String cfgFile = getPath(".cfg", this.getActivity());
        String weightsFile = getPath(".weights", this.getActivity());

        if (cfgFile != null && weightsFile != null) {
            net = new Darknet(cfgFile, weightsFile);
        }
        //mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked when camera preview has been stopped for some reason.
     * No frames will be delivered via onCameraFrame() callback after this method is called.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {

    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked when delivery of the frame needs to be done.
     * The returned values - is a modified frame which needs to be displayed on the screen.
     * TODO: pass the parameters specifying the format of the frame (BPP, YUV or RGB and etc)
     *
     * @param inputFrame
     */
    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2RGB);
        Mat mRgbaT = frame;
/*        old_mRgbaT = frame.t();
        Core.flip(old_mRgbaT, old_mRgbaT, 1);
        Imgproc.resize(old_mRgbaT, mRgbaT, frame.size());
        old_mRgbaT.release();
        */
        Mat temp = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < OrientationIsValid; i++) {

            temp = frame.t();
            Core.flip(temp, temp, 1);
            Imgproc.resize(temp, mRgbaT, frame.size());
            temp.release();
        }

        int cols = mRgbaT.cols();
        int rows = mRgbaT.rows();
        Size cropSize;
        if ((float) cols / rows > 1) {
            cropSize = new Size(rows * 1, rows);
        } else {
            cropSize = new Size(cols, cols / 1);
        }
        int y1 = (int) (rows - cropSize.height) / 2;
        int y2 = (int) (y1 + cropSize.height);
        int x1 = (int) (cols - cropSize.width) / 2;
        int x2 = (int) (x1 + cropSize.width);
        Mat subFrame = mRgbaT.submat(y1, y2, x1, x2);
        cols = subFrame.cols();
        rows = subFrame.rows();
        int sevarity = 0;
        if (net != null) {
            double confidence, xCenter, yCenter, width, height = 0;
            Mat retMat = net.forwardLoadedNetwork(mRgbaT);
            for (int i = 0; i < retMat.rows(); i++) {
                confidence = retMat.get(i, 5)[0];
                if (confidence > confidenceThresh) {
                    printMat(retMat.row(i));
                    //System.out.println("YESSSSSS");
                    xCenter = retMat.get(i, 0)[0] * mRgbaT.cols();
                    yCenter = retMat.get(i, 1)[0] * mRgbaT.rows();
                    width = retMat.get(i, 2)[0] * mRgbaT.cols();
                    height = retMat.get(i, 3)[0] * mRgbaT.rows();
                    Imgproc.rectangle(mRgbaT, new Point((xCenter - width / 2), (yCenter - height / 2)), new Point(xCenter + width / 2
                            , yCenter + height / 2), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
                    Imgproc.putText(mRgbaT, String.format("%.4f", new Double(confidence * 100)) + "%", new Point((xCenter - width / 2), (yCenter - height / 2) - 5)
                            , 1, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
                    sevarity++;
                }
            }
            retMat.release();
            subFrame.release();
            if (sevarity > 0) {
                createPothole(sevarity);
            }
        } else {
            //Log.i("System", "Problem forwarding network");
        }
        return mRgbaT;
    }

    private Pothole createPothole(int severity) {
        Pothole pothole = null;
        if (this.getActivity() != null) {
            Location location = ((MainActivity) this.getActivity()).getLocation();
            if (location != null) {
                pothole = new Pothole(location, createPotholeId(), severity);
                addToPotholeList(pothole);
            }
        }

        return pothole;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the id string for a pothole.
     *
     * @return the pothole id
     */
    public String createPotholeId() {
        PotholeList list = PotholeList.getInstance();
        int num = 0;
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            String lastId = list.get(list.size() - 1).getId();
            num = Integer.parseInt(lastId.substring(1));
        }
        String retId = "p" + (num + 1);
        return retId;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the returned matrix outputted from the network.
     *
     * @param mat the mat to print
     */
    private void printMat(Mat mat) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows(); i++) {
            //System.out.print("[ ");
            for (int n = 0; n < mat.cols(); n++) {
                try {
                    //System.out.printf( "%.2f ", mat.get(i, n)[0]);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    //System.out.print( " " );
                }

            }
            //System.out.println("]");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        try {
            if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
                Log.d("Debug", "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
                mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(BaseLoaderCallback .SUCCESS);


            }
            else {
                Log.d("Debug", "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
                OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this.getActivity(), mLoaderCallback);
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "OpenCV is required to run this feature. Please install OpenCV from the Google Play Store or download the APK from their official website.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the path of a file and create it in the app memory.
     *
     * @param fileType the file to find
     * @param context  context
     * @return the pathname
     */
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    private static String getPath(String fileType, Context context) {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        String[] pathNames = {};
        String fileName = "";
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        try {
            pathNames = assetManager.list("yolo");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (String filePath : pathNames) {
            System.out.println(filePath);
            if (filePath.endsWith(fileType)) {
                fileName = filePath;
                break;
            }
        }
        BufferedInputStream inputStream;
        try {
            // Read data from assets.
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(assetManager.open(fileName));
            byte[] data = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            inputStream.read(data);
            inputStream.close();

            // Create copy file in storage.
            File outFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            os.write(data);
            os.close();
            // Return a path to file which may be read in common way.
            return outFile.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "Failed to upload a file");
        }
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Adds the pothole to the pothole list.
     *
     * @param pothole the pothole to add
     */
    public boolean addToPotholeList(Pothole pothole) {
        return potholeList.add(pothole);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        OrientationIsValid++;
        if (OrientationIsValid > 3) {
            OrientationIsValid = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        confidenceThresh = (double) i / 100;
        TextView textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.confidence);
        textView.setText("Confidence Threshold: " + (confidenceThresh * 100) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Your `mLoaderCallback` is `null` because even though you created a class level variable of `BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback`, you don't initialize it. Instead you create a local variable `BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback` in `onCreateView`. Correctly assign it like `mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this.getActivity())` to fix.

Comment: But the stacktrace tells you what is wrong, you simply needed to debug it to check what was wrong.

Comment: please can you tell me how to initialize mLoaderCallback
and in the stacktrace OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV